# Getting a value of null in a global variable that set a value from onDataChange

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to set value to a global variable in OnDataChange() and share it to other methods but it turns out that it always gives me a null

```
String mCurrentState; //global variable

     mUsersDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  mCurrentState = "normal";
             }
             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
       }
```

Is there any way to set a global variable inside a onDataChange()

Comment: in what way is it a global variable? Does not look very global to me

Comment: If it's null, it's probably that you're trying to read the variable **before** it's been set **asynchronously** by the onDataChange method. It might also be a visibility issue between threads. But with the code you posted, we can't know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Comment: No, there is not. Please see the duplicate to see why is this happening and how you can solve this.